# Join over the same table (using a non PK column)

Tags: nhibernate

I have a table which needs a relationship over itself.

**Table Example:**

> ```
> field_PK ---> Primary key 
> field_A ---> used as Foreign key to field_B 
> field_B
> ```

**Mapping:**

```
  <id name="field_PK">
      <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>

    ......

  <bag name="childs">
      <key column="field_A"  update="false"/>
      <one-to-many class="example"/>
  </bag>

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I've noticed that by default NH uses the PK to perform joins... How can I tell NH to join field_A on field_B (instead of joining field_A on the PK)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `property-ref` attribute to join to any mapped property.